# Should I use retrofit rest client given I am already using Spring framework in my webapp

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-webflow, retrofit

I am using Spring, Jersey to create my webapp which also interacts with other webservices.
I am wondering if I should use Retrofit rest client or use Jersey client. A section of my pom looks like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Jersey + Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use what ever client you want. If you have service Interface from server side I would recommend to use Jersey 2.x. It can generate proxy for you so you can call a service as if it is local method.

Comment: @Dymtro: I think we can do the same with Retrofit as well. Are there any obvious reason to chose one over the other? Thanks.

Comment: You said you already use Jersey for server. I consider it to be a reason to use the same framework for client as well. And if you use Jersey 2.x it will provide same convenience as Retrofit does. BTW, Jersey has test support which I like very much.